# Video - Video Format Not Supported - OTA-13

Tags: ubuntu-touch, video

Recently I up dated my `Meizu Pro5` running `15.04` to `OTA-13`. Video did not work before with `OTA-12` and still does not work (worked with `OTA-11`).

Now I'm getting the following error message: `"video format not supported"`

Any help here?

Comment: What format are you talking about???

Comment: That is what the error message reads. It is the format in which the camera saves its' own video. Sounds strange does it not? The format that the camera itself shoots is not supported by the self same application to play back?  Is a puzzlement.

Comment: Yes, sounds ugly. Sorry, don't know why. Have you tried to play it with a computer?

Comment: @BjarneRoß - Just took your suggestion, Bjarne Roß. The video format is mp4. It plays on my Ubuntu desktop, sound is fine, however. when the phone is held vertically, any camera movement is involved the playback image severely pixilates. Front and rear cameras give the same result. Plays well on the PC  in horizontal or wide screen mode and the still camera works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug Report filed. Work-around = Copy mp4 video to PC and view it there. To eliminate pixilation - ALWAYS shoot video in wide screen mode.